# Get List of Users for a Specific Local Time

Tags: javascript, sql, timezone

In my database, I have a list of users with the user ids and their UTC offset in minutes. It's in a PostgreSQL database which I access through sequelize in my node application.

For example:

```
ID, offset
1, -540 
2, -330 
...
...
```

I want to create a query that, when run, gets me a list of users that have passed 12pm noon their local time.

For example, when UTC time is 7am and we run the query, then for user Id 2, the local time is 12:30pm, and for userId 1, the local time is 4pm. So, the query will get me [1,2]

However, when UTC time is 5am and we run the query, then for user 1, the local time is 1pm, but for user 2, the local time is 10:30am. So the query result will be [1].

I'm confused about how to structure my code to make this happen. I don't need the syntax. I just need the logic for how I should form my query or my sequelize code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `(now() - offset) % 86400 >= 43200` perhaps?

Comment: @Nick I'll be glad if you could explain what you did here?

Comment: Well, firstly I did make a minor mistake, it should be `now()` (UTC timestamp in seconds) - `offset * 60` (offset in minutes converted to seconds), which gives you the local timestamp, then modulo the number of seconds in a day to get the time of day in seconds and then finally checking if it's after 12:00 (which converted to seconds is 43200)

Comment: Thanks. I think I can work on a solution around this. But doesn't now() return milliseconds?

Comment: It returns a timestamp which should be in seconds. although note you might want `extract(epoch from now())` rather than just `now`

Comment: Is it possible to structure this condition with just 'offset' on the left hand side such as offset > (condition) or offset < (condition)? This can help me set the condition in query.

Comment: I was trying this which seems to be ok - offset < -(differenceInMinutes((new Date()).setUTCHours(12, 0, 0, 0), new Date()))

Comment: Yeah, that looks reasonable...

Comment: Thanks. You think it's checking the condition correctly?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me. But it is late...

Comment: If you did get a working solution you should post it as an answer so others can benefit.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. For example, when UTC time is 2am, my target with setUTCHours is setting to 12pm of the new day, when timezones like UTC-5 and all are still on the previous day. so this condition fails.

Comment: Your condition works correctly, but I need to find a way to convert it such that there's only offset on left hand side such as offset<condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247934/discussion-between-asanas-and-nick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to compute if the local time is after noon is to convert the UTC timestamp (in seconds) to local time by adding the timezone offset (in minutes) * 60, then taking the result modulo 86400 (seconds in a day) and testing to see if it is greater than or equal to 43200` (12:00) i.e.

```
afternoon = ((now()-offset*60) % 86400) >= 43200
```

This can be refactored in terms of the timezone offset by computing

```
const n = new Date()
const t = n.getUTCHours() * 60 + n.getUTCMinutes()
const afternoon = offset > t || offset <= t - 720 && offset > t - 1440
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Something seems wrong with offset > t || offset <= t - 720 && offset > t - 1440. The first part is offset>t and the last part is offset > t-1440. Are there any brackets to be used?

Comment: Would it be: afternoon = offset > t || (offset <= t - 720 && offset > t - 1440)

Comment: @asanas the brackets are not necessary because `&&` takes precedence over `||`, but the way you have parenthesised it is the intention. The last part (`offset > t - 1440`) is there *only* to deal with the special case where the UTC time is noon and the timezone offset is -720.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the standard.

For example, when UTC time is 7am, the standard will be -300

=> So, your query will be like

```
SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE offset <= ${standard} (In this case, standard is -300)
```

If when UTC time is 1pm, the standard will be 600, -660

=> The query will be

```
SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE -660 <= offset <= 600
```

Comment: What do you mean by standard? You're suggesting having multiple queries? How did you calculate this standard?